# Laravel Echo authentication via API

Tags: laravel, pusher, laravel-echo, pusher-js

Using `Pusher` in conjunction with `Echo` on the client, I'm attempting to authenticate a private channel via api using `Bearer` Authorization header token - however I'm met with the following logs **(THE LAST LOG BEING THE ERROR)**:

> **Pusher** :  : ["State changed","initialized -> connecting"]

> **Pusher** :  :
> ["Connecting",{"transport":"ws","url":"ws://ws-mt1.pusher.com:80/app/************?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.3&flash=false"}]

> **Pusher** :  : ["State changed","connecting -> connected with
> new socket ID 224550.32180982"]

> **Pusher** :  : ["No callbacks
> on private-App.User.17 for pusher:subscription_error"]

> **Pusher** :  : ["Error: JSON returned from auth endpoint was
> invalid, yet status code was 200. Data was: <!doctype html>\n<html
> class="en" lang="en">\n\t\n\t\t\t<meta
> charset="utf-...

Seems like my server is just returning the webpage rather than a JSON response.

**Here is my Client setup:**

```
Pusher.logToConsole = true

const PusherClient = new Pusher(PUSHER_APP_KEY,{
    cluster: PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    wsHost: `ws-${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}.pusher.com`,
    wssPort: 443,
    enabledTransports: ['ws'],
    forceTLS: true,
    encrypted: true,
    auth: {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    },
    authEndpoint: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/broadcasting/auth'
});

return new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    client: PusherClient
})
```

**Broadcast routes defined in `api.php` on Laravel server:**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    Broadcast::routes();
});
```

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the error log completely

Comment: Try to match your authentication token you have created to validate user.

Comment: Plz would mind take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67605266/how-to-read-smart-contracts-from-tronscan-org-using-laravel-and-json-rpc

Answer (score 1):

First you can setup client side without laravel-echo, just with pusher-js. In the version I'm using there shouldn't be Content-Type header:

```js
    auth: {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer CLIENT_TOKEN`,
        }

    },
```

You must make sure the **channel** you're subscribing is available and all pusher **app parameters** and also **user's token** are inserted correctly.